# Where should I move the mongodb dump in production remote server?

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I created a mongodb dump of database in my localmachine. It was put in dump folder as "myProject". Within myProject I had two files one ending with .bson and other with metadata.json.

I moved the myProject folder to my remote server.

I used mongorestore on myProject folder.

I have installed mongodb in my remote server.

I got error /dbpath (/data/db/) does not exist and  I fixed them using first solution given here.

1. Now how will mongodb in remote server know the location of my restored dump?
2. Should I move the .json and .bson file to a new folder named same as the database name ("myProject" placed inside /data/db/)?
3. If I need to move the restored dump where should I move them?
4. Mine is a spring web app and I am running in tomcat sever. So far in my localmachine, the spring bean had the host value as "localhost". Should it be changed to my remote server Ip address, when I am running the application in remote server or Is it fine if the value is localhost?

Comment: This really has little to do with the application or tomcat server. It seems you have made a dump of a local database and now you want to restore it to your production MongoDB server. Have you done the restore or just moved the files? Have you read the documentation for [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)?

Comment: I did mongorestore --port 27017 /DirectoryWhereIHad_.bson_And.json . 
1) Now I am thinking of redoing mongorestore --dbpath /data/db/ instead of mongorestore --dbpath /srv/mongodb. But I don't have /dump folder by default in my production server. 
2) Should I create one and move the scp-ed.json and .bson files to /dump foler?

Comment: But, wait, I am able to do mongo and in the monog shell I can use my collection and when I use db.coll.find() I could see some results. So, Does that mean I have done correctly already?

Comment: Try accessing data from your webapp to confirm if you are done.

Comment: I tried from webapp, but I am not able to see the data